How to use if statements inside of groups in a dataframe in R?
I would like to perform rowwise if statements with a condition that is colwise. Preferably using only base R and dplyr.
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3)
year <- c(2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2015, 2016, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2015, 2016, 2018)
value <- c(100, NA, 150, 0, 200, 120, 0, NA, 130, 140, 0, 160, 170, NA, 180, 190, 200, 0, 150, 160)

df <- data.frame(id, year, value)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(0 && any(value > 0), NA, value))

Specifically, I want to replace 0 with an NA, if there are other non-zero values in the same column, in the same group.
Later on, I would choose the row with least NAs for all the duplicate rows.
The above code throws an error, because the value in the false of if_else() returns the whole column (inside of the group) as a vector.
I would imagine something like either a vectorised if() (without else), or a placeholder for the if_else() that basically says "do nothing".
A dplyr placeholder for rows or the specific value could also help, but I couldn't find anything appropriate.
If someone has a general approach on how to do these kind "row-by-row with group context operations", I would appreciate any insights.

& is vectorized, && is not. If you're using vectorized if_else, you almost always want to be using &.

@GregorThomas Thanks, I wasn't aware of that difference!

I don't think the example data includes any examples of a group with a zero but no non-NA non-zeroes, so I add one here at the bottom.
df |>
  bind_rows(data.frame(id = 10, year = 2015, value = c(0,0,NA))) |>
  mutate(value2 = if_else(any(value[!is.na(value)] != 0) & value == 0, NA, value), 
         .by = c(id, year))

   

The if_else here checks if the group defined with .by = c(id, year) has any non-NA, non-zero values, AND the current value is zero, in which case we'd switch to NA.
Here, rows 4, 7, 11, and 18 are changed 0 to NA. But rows 21-22 are left as is, since that group has no valid values.
   id year value value2
1   1 2015   100    100
2   1 2015    NA     NA
3   1 2016   150    150
4   1 2016     0     NA
5   1 2017   200    200
6   2 2015   120    120
7   2 2016     0     NA
8   2 2016    NA     NA
9   3 2017   130    130
10  3 2017   140    140
11  3 2018     0     NA
12  4 2015   160    160
13  4 2016   170    170
14  4 2018    NA     NA
15  5 2017   180    180
16  5 2018   190    190
17  5 2018   200    200
18  1 2015     0     NA
19  2 2016   150    150
20  3 2018   160    160
21 10 2015     0      0
22 10 2015     0      0
23 10 2015    NA     NA


In case there is interest in a base R solution you could use lapply and split to break the data into a list of data.frames by some set of variables then apply a function to each subset of the data. This has the will sort rows by the variables in split, so be aware of that difference.
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(id, year, value),
  data.frame(id = 1, year = 2019, value = c(0, NA)) # adding id:year with only 0 and NA values
)

df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df[, c("id", "year")]), function(d) {
  d$value2 <- if_else(any(d$value != 0, na.rm = TRUE) & d$value == 0, NA, d$value)
  d
}))
rownames(df2) <- NULL # using split like this makes rownames of year.id

> df2
   id year value value2
1   1 2015   100    100
2   1 2015    NA     NA
3   1 2015     0     NA
4   2 2015   120    120
5   4 2015   160    160
6   1 2016   150    150
7   1 2016     0     NA
8   2 2016     0     NA
9   2 2016    NA     NA
10  2 2016   150    150
11  4 2016   170    170
12  1 2017   200    200
13  3 2017   130    130
14  3 2017   140    140
15  5 2017   180    180
16  3 2018     0     NA
17  3 2018   160    160
18  4 2018    NA     NA
19  5 2018   190    190
20  5 2018   200    200
21  1 2019     0      0
22  1 2019    NA     NA


